# Powershell: pass in multiline txt file values as an array in param statement

Tags: powershell

I have a text file containing a list of servers, one per line, like:

```
SERVER1
SERVER2
SERVER3
```

When I do a `Get-Content` on the file, I do see the output as:

```
SERVER1
SERVER2
SERVER3
```

So now I am writing a function that I want to take in the multiple servers as an array, and iterate over the array in the function. The function is currently like this:

```
function Get-LocalAdministrators 
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string[]]$computers
    )

    foreach ($computername in $computers)
    {
        $ADMINS = get-wmiobject -computername $computername -query "select * from win32_groupuser where GroupComponent=""Win32_Group.Domain='$computername',Name='administrators'""" | % {$_.partcomponent}

        foreach ($ADMIN in $ADMINS) 
        {
            $admin = $admin.replace("\\$computername\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain=","") # trims the results for a user
            $admin = $admin.replace("\\$computername\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain=","") # trims the results for a group
            $admin = $admin.replace('",Name="',"\")
            $admin = $admin.REPLACE("""","") # strips the last "

            $objOutput = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Machinename = $($computername)
                Fullname = ($admin)
                #DomainName  =$admin.split("\")[0]
                #UserName = $admin.split("\")[1]
            }

        $objReport+=@($objOutput)
        }

        return $objReport
    }
}
```

Then I plan to call the function as:

```
Get-Content “C:\temp\computers.txt” | Get-LocalAdministrators
```

However, when I run the function, I can see that the value of $computers is `{SERVER3}` (i.e. only the last line in the file.) I have tried to find the answer to this via teh Google, and although there are a lot of array references/examples, I cannot find one where it combines reading the values from a file, into an array in a `param` statement. Please forgive my PS newb ignorance, and provide the clue that I need... Thanks.

UPDATE: Link to screenshot of script running in PowerGUI Script Editor showing the value of $computers during the run: [debug run screenshot](http://i1096.photobucket.com/albums/g330/willdennis/Get-LocalAdministrators-debug.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass objects via the pipeline into a function, only one is passed into your function at a time - not the whole array. So you don't need the `foreach` loop, nor do you need to make `$computers` an array in the function.

Also, when you have a pipeline function, you should be making use of the `begin`,`process` and `end` keywords. Each denotes a script block - `begin` is a scriptblock that is executed *once* (when the pipeline is "set up"), `process` is the scriptblock to be executed for each object passed via the pipeline, and `end` is just like `begin` only it runs after the last item has passed through.

So minimally, your function should be this:

```
function Get-LocalAdministrators
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [string]$computer
    )
process{
$ADMINS = get-wmiobject -computername $computername -query "select * from win32_groupuser where GroupComponent=""Win32_Group.Domain='$computername',Name='administrators'""" | % {$_.partcomponent}
# Do other stuff here
}
}
```

[The MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847829.aspx) says (this is in `get-help about_functions` - there's more to it than this):

> Piping Objects to Functions
>         Any function can take input from the pipeline. You can control how a 
>         function processes input from the pipeline using Begin, Process, and End 
>         keywords. The following sample syntax shows the three keywords:
>
> ```
>       function <name> { 
>           begin {<statement list>}
>           process {<statement list>}
>           end {<statement list>}
>       }
>
>   The Begin statement list runs one time only, at the beginning of 
>   the function.  
>
>   The Process statement list runs one time for each object in the pipeline.
>   While the Process block is running, each pipeline object is assigned to 
>   the $_ automatic variable, one pipeline object at a time. 
>
>   After the function receives all the objects in the pipeline, the End 
>   statement list runs one time. If no Begin, Process, or End keywords are 
>   used, all the statements are treated like an End statement list.
> ```

---

**Edit:** After seeing the full code added by the OP, this works. Note that I have made the changes to your code as I describe above.

```
function Get-LocalAdministrators 
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
        [string]$computer
    )

    process{
        $ADMINS = get-wmiobject -computername $computer -query "select * from win32_groupuser where GroupComponent=""Win32_Group.Domain='$computer',Name='administrators'""" | % {$_.partcomponent}

        foreach ($ADMIN in $ADMINS) 
        {
            $admin = $admin.replace("\\$computername\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain=","") # trims the results for a user
            $admin = $admin.replace("\\$computername\root\cimv2:Win32_Group.Domain=","") # trims the results for a group
            $admin = $admin.replace('",Name="',"\")
            $admin = $admin.REPLACE("""","") # strips the last "

            $objOutput = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                Machinename = $($computer)
                Fullname = ($admin)
                #DomainName  =$admin.split("\")[0]
                #UserName = $admin.split("\")[1]
            }

        $objReport+=@($objOutput)
        }

        $objReport
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but this still doesn't fix the problem that `$computers` has only one value (the last line) from the pipeline from `Get-Content`... The function does run, but only gives me output for the last server named in the file... I'm assuming because $computers only has the one value in it. How do I pass in the multiple values (lines) from the file so that `$computers` has multiple values in it?

Comment: **Get-Content** reads all the lines into an array, where each element is one line. **$computers** should have as many value as lines in the file. My guess is that you're using an output file and overwriting it each time, so in the end you only have the results from the final iteration. It would help if you'd post the entire function.

Comment: You haven't shown how you're doing your output. `$computers` *does* have all the values in it (I ran the code myself), and if you replace the `$admins` line with just `$computer` you will see all 3 names output. Which leads me to the conclusion that there's something in the output that you aren't showing us that's causing your issue - that `(..)` section.

Comment: edited original post to: **1)** add full function code **2)** add link to screenshot showing script running in PowerGUI script editor showing value of `$computers` vs the output of `Get-Content` in the bottom left pane

Comment: @WillDennis please, please re-read my post in full. You need to drop the `foreach` and make the parameter a single `string`, not an array. Your OP is also flawed in that you're calling `return` within the `foreach` loop - so it's only going to run through one iteration!

Comment: Thanks, @alroc - I see now... I was being thrown in that I expected the variable `$computers` to contain all the servers in the file... I see now via debug how the function iterates thru them, once per line via the pipeline. As well, I see the misplaced $objReport return. It does work now, but I'm getting strange output... It repeats the prior output lines for each server in every iteration of the function. Take a look here: http://pastebin.com/js1A2P2k

Comment: You're appending to `$objreport` with each item that comes through the pipeline, not replacing it. You need to reset that variable back to empty at the beginning of your `process` block if you don't want that behavior.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out, @alroc - added a `$objReport = @()` before the foreach, and now I've got the correct output! Appreciate you taking the time to educate me.

Comment: You could also create the collection in your `begin` block and append to that within `process`, then output it in the `end` block.